# Polybase with Cloudera 5.9

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sql-server-2016

We are looking to connect to Cloudera with polybase.  MSDN says we can connect to Cloudera 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, and 5.5 on Linux [PolyBase Connectivity Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143174.aspx)

Does anyone know if you can use PolyBase with a Cloudera version over 5.5? We are looking to use 5.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has updated the documentation

Option 6: Cloudera 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, and 5.9 on Linux

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143174.aspx